# How to pass header to URL in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a question regarding how to view a PDF from URL.
I’m using `flutter_pdfview` library and I try to get a PDF from an URL and to view it in my Flutter app.
The problem is that my URL can be accessed ONLY with a token (session ID/header), but I don’t know how to pass it because is not working on the way I do it at the moment.
Here is an example of how the owner of the `flutter_pdfview` library is getting the PDF from an URL (without a Header): https://github.com/endigo/flutter_pdfview/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart#L49

And here is my code where I don’t know how else to pass the header than like this:

```
Future<File> createFileOfPdfUrl() async {
    Completer<File> completer = Completer();

    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("Start download file from internet!");
    }
    try {
      String url =
          "$customURL.pdf";
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("url: $url");
      }

      final filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
      var client = HttpClient();
      HttpClientRequest request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
      request.headers.add(
          HttpHeaders.acceptHeader,
          HeaderValue(
              "text/plain", {'APPAUTH': '${widget.authService.loginToken}'})); // this method doesn't seems to work for me. I'm getting an empty PDF.

      var response = await request.close();
      var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
      var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("Download files");
        print("${dir.path}/$filename");
      }
      File file = File("${dir.path}/$filename");

      await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
      completer.complete(file);
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Error parsing asset file!');
    }

    return completer.future;
  }
```

Comment: could you print your loginToken to see its format? I want too see does it have `Bearer` with it?

Comment: I think you should place this token into the `Authorization` header, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization).

Comment: My token it is a key-value pair and the `key` is a string called "APPAUTH" and the `value` is a 32 characters string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DO NOT do this:**

```
request.headers.add(
          HttpHeaders.acceptHeader, // here is the problem
          HeaderValue(
              "text/plain", {'APPAUTH': '${widget.authService.loginToken}'}));
```

**SOLUTION for me:**

```
request.headers.add("APPAUTH", "12345abcde67890defgh");
```

For some reason if you provide a `HeaderValue` you also need to provide a string value before it, which can be `HttpHeaders.acceptHeader` or `HttpHeaders.serverHeader` etc. I tried a lot of them from that enum list and none worked for me so I used the above solution where you don't need to pass that `HttpHeader` value type.